# shell/ksh syntax for a condition inside inline input

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

Completely forgot how to do it correctly, and probably forgot the correct terms as well.

Long inline input (I think this is what it's called), using the Teradata bteq as an example client reading the stdin (same as Oracle sql*plus or Sybase isql etc) - so this could be pretty much anything.

```
bteq <<!

select sql_column1
`if [ "$mode" == "mode1" ]; then`
  , sql_column2
`fi`
  , sql_column3
from table1
;

!
```

Here if the mode is "mode1" - I output 3 sql_columns, otherwise two. Now, imagine this is a very very large input, so these conditional manipulations can be very handy.
I'm pretty sure I have done this before, but covid-19 completely flushed my memory.
With this syntax I'm getting: syntax error at line xx: `then' unmatched.

How do I do this right, and what are the correct Unix terms for what I called here as  a) inline input; and b) inline condition?

Comment: The term is "here document".

Answer (score 1):

If your desire is to end up with a multi-line SQL statement, then you don't need a "here document" in this specific case because strings can span lines. You can do it easily like this, so long as your text doesn't have embedded quotes.

```
if [ "$mode" == "mode1" ]; then
   col2="
, sql_column2"
else
   col2=""
fi

stm="select sql_column1$col2
, sql_column3
from table1
;"

echo "stm='$stm'"
```

If you don't need a multi-line SQL statement, then the code is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either Jeff's revision, or this one, if the "here document" and multiple conditional inclusions are too long to want to break the logic:

```
bteq <<!

select sql_column1
`if [ "$mode" == "mode1" ]; then
 echo \"
  , sql_column2
 \"
fi`
  , sql_column3
from table1
;

!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem on a lot of ways. How can someone read your code after mixing bteq, SQL, Bash and special tests? I think the next approach might help:
I started with replacing `bteq` by `cat` for testing.
You can replace your test with

```
[[ "${mode}" == "mode1" ]] && echo ", sql_column2"
```

Using this in your here document (using $() and not backtics) results in

```
cat << END
select sql_column1
$( [[ "${mode}" == "mode1" ]] && echo ", sql_column2")
, sql_column3
from table1
;
EOF
```

This is not much better for the readers eyes. Now what? Make a function!

```
mode1_column() {
  [[ "${mode}" == "mode1" ]] && echo ", sql_column2"
}

cat << EOF
  select sql_column1
  $(mode1_column)
  , sql_column3
  from table1
  ;
EOF
```